# Leveraging the CSS sibling selector within BEM

Tags: css, bem

Say I have a block called `.my-block`. Depending on whether a specific element, say, `.my-header` appears before it, I need to style it differently. Because this is easy to do with the CSS sibling selector, I'd like to avoid adding conditionals to my HTML templates and add modifiers to `my-block`. I've considering two options.

Option 1)

```
<body class="my-block-container">
  <header class="my-header my-block-container__header"></header>
  <div class="my-block-container__my-block"</div>
</body>
```

Option 2)

```
  <header class="my-block-sibling"></header>
  <div class="my-block"</div>
```

I dislike option 1, because no classes will be applied directly to `.my-block-container` and `.my-block-container__header`. Moreover, I'd have to either rename the children of `.my-block` and apply the somewhat vague `my-block-container` as a block name, or introduce a new block-level name with the only purpose of selecting a sibling.

I dislike option 2, because it's not truly BEM; there's no true block-level name.

Should I accept that I've reached the limits of BEM naming, or is there a convention for this kind of situation?

Answer (score 1):

Did you considered using a modifier for this case?

```html
<body>
  <header class="my-header"></header>
  <div class="my-block my-block--after-a-header"</div>
</body>
```

This will allow us to have separated styles between `header` and `block`, and to style differently a `block` when it's after a `header`.

Next step will be to rename the modifier class to express what it does (and not when to use it), so it will allow you to reuse it in an other context in the future.
For example: `.my-header--small` will be more explicit than `.my-block--after-a-header`

Comment: The problem is not that the header needs to be styled differently; the block needs to be styled depending on whether or not a header appears before it!

Comment: @kslstn OK. I updated my answer. It doesn't change the technical choice behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your idea to use a sibling selector (`+`) is a good one in this scenario.

Here is a working example of BEM + sibling selector in practice,

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.my-block-container {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  height: 144px;
  margin-right: 12px;
  text-align: center;
}

.my-block-container__header {
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.my-block {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 60px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.my-block-container__my-block {
  margin-top: 24px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}

.my-block-container__header + .my-block-container__my-block {
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="my-block-container">
  <div class="my-block my-block-container__my-block">Not preceded by &lt;header&gt;</div>
</div>

<div class="my-block-container">
  <header class="my-block-container__header">Header</header>
  <div class="my-block my-block-container__my-block">Preceded by &lt;header&gt;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's basically my solution 1, right? Considering `my-block` can appear inside any container and thus no styles will be applied to `.my-block-container`, that would introduce a class name and thus code that's not actually used or referenced at all. Not a huge problem feels excessive for a naming system.

Comment: It is basically your solution 1, yes. If `my-block` can appear inside any container, you _could_ use something like the following: `[class$="__my-block"] {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}` and then `[class$="__header"] + [class$="__my-block"] {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}` That would enable `__my-block` and `__header` to have _any_ Block prefix. This strays from _pure_ BEM, but it's clean and efficient.

Comment: Thanks, interesting, I didn't know about the possibility of selecting elements based on the end of a class name. But if we're straying from BEM anyway, I think my solution 2 is simplest as it doesn't require any additional selectors, the `my-block-sibling` name is descriptive (and used in the CSS, so I don't risk deleting it when removing unused classes).

Comment: I don't disagree - I think your solution 2 is as good as anything we might come up with in this situation. Since we've moved away from _classical BEM_, if the preceding sibling is always intended to be a `<header>`, you could even use: `.my-block {background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);}` and then `header+.my-block {background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);}`